# Does any OS setting affect ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, linux-kernel, executorservice

Is there any OS setting/option that might have effect on ExecutorService performing way?

I got different result with same code below in different OS.

```
 ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for ( int j = 0 ; j< 1000 ; j ++) {
        es.execute(() -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            long start = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(threadName + "- start");

            System.out.println(threadName + "- end, elapsed time:" + TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - start, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
        });
    }
```

When I run this code from my laptop(Windows), I got result like below which was I expected.

```
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-3- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:86
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:137
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-3- end, elapsed time:155
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:38
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-3- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:47
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:91
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-3- end, elapsed time:94
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:91
```

Problem is when I run the same code in CentOS server, result was totally different.

```
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:5
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:19
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-1- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-1- start
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:10382
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:5
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-2- start
pool-1-thread-2- end, elapsed time:4
pool-1-thread-2- start
```

FYI, I did not add any of JVM options.and those two device has same jdk version.
There might be some unusual OS/kernel setting on CentOS because this server is for some special purpose. but I am not familiar with those settings.

I guess big number just before working thread changed might be a hint, but could not find an answer.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I would try with longer operation, like add some sleep inside. As this might be affected by speed of operation and speed of thread creation/resume on given PC. As just first thread is already done with task before loop starting that task goes to next one

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such setting available on any OS.
Thread gets time when there is a processor available which is idle.
This further depends on the number of processor available and speed of the processor.

Comment: thanks for your advice, It helps me to find an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of a program like the one you have written will depend on:

- the thread scheduler which is operating system dependent, and
- and the number of cores available to run the code which is hardware dependent.

The fact that your program behaves differently when you change the operating system and (probably) the hardware (or virtual hardware) platform is unsurprising.

Another think that will affect the behavior in this case will be how output to `System.out` is handled, and how that affects thread scheduling.

There are probably also OS settings that *could* change scheduler behavior, but in this case you don't need to look to such things to explain the difference that you are seeing.

Comment: was able to get closer to an answer by your hint, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer. 
Simply kernel parameter isolcpus was blocking CPU scheduling.

I've isolcpus to lock some cores of CPU for thread affinity, and I dedicated those isolated cores to Java process by taskset -p PID.

I did not know isolated cpus are out of OS CPU scheduling. eventually Java process runs only on remaining 2 cpu cores which result differently in 2nd case.(taskset setting was useless because isolated cpu was already out of OS CPU scheduling)

In most usual cases, It would be simple to release isolcpus kernel param in this case.

And alternative way to live with isolcpus was adding `chrt`

```
taskset -p 1-17 chrt -r 1 java <classPath>
```

Choosing APPT scheduling strategy will be a different matter but I was able to get the answer that I want by this.